# Access controller data from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing ASP.NET Core application. To keep controllers lean, most of the data manipulation is done in ViewModels. Everything works fine - the two problems, however, are

1. ViewModels don't have access to ControllerContext information (or I can't figure out how to get it). For example, Session, User and whatever else Controller gets for free.
2. ViewModels don't accept Dependency Injection (again, or I can't figure out how to pass it along). For example, if I have constructor `MyController(ApplicationDbContext db)` I get `db` passed without any problems. However, if I have `ComplexViewModel(ApplicationDbContext db)` I get `null` passed in. Obviously, I have exactly the same `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()` in Startup

Right now I am passing whatever is required from Controller to ViewModel explicitly. But it feels that there should be a better way.

Comment: I suggest that your ViewModels contain no behavior and that you move all behavior to custom services. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View models are supposed to be simple POCOs to transfer data between the views and action methods. I think it is a bad idea to mix all your business logic (or even data access) to view models. You may consider doing that in services. You can inject this services to your controllers.

For example.

Yo get a User information, you may consider creating a service

```
public interface IUserService
{
  UserDto GetUser(int id);
}
public class UserService : IUserService
{ 
  IUserDataAccess userDataAccess;
  public UserService(IUserDataAccess userDataAccess)
  {
    this.userDataAccess=userDataAccess;
  }
  public UserDto GetUser(int id)
  {
     // with this.userDataAccess, get a User and map to UserDto
    // to do : return something
  }
}
```

So your controllers will stay lean

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
  private readonly IUserService userService;
  public UserController(IUserService userService)
  {
    this.userService = userService;
  }
  public ActionResult Details(int id)
  {
    var userDto= this.userService.GetUser(id);
    return View(userDto);
  }
}
```

Now you can have a `UserDataAccess` which query your data and inject that to the `UserService` class.

With this approach your view model does not have any idea what data access technology you are using. Imagine tomorrow you decided to ditch EF for performance reason and want to switch to Dapper, you simply need to create a new implementation of your `IUserDataAccess` called "`DapperUserDataAccess`" and udpate your DI config registration to use that. No other code change :)

Comment: Conceptually, I agree. However, as in any line-of-business application there is *a lot* of business logic and data access. Creating a service looked like unnecessary duplication. To build up on your example, sample ViewModel would be `CustomerCreditViewModel` that gets the data about customer, order history, but also need information about the user's approval limits (the example is completely made-up). ViewModel *seemed* to be a good place to do all this, and it worked well so far. But probably it's time to rethink the approach.

Comment: I totally disagree. IMHO, I think you should not mix your view models with data /business logic. They should be lean flat POCOs. It should not have any knowledge about your data access. Again, It is my personal opinion, I do not have any right to impose that on your. You are free to follow what you think is correct.

Comment: Heh - I *don't* think I disagree with you ;) What I was saying, putting business logic in VM *initially* looked like a good idea (at least, better than in Controllers, where it resided previously) - but now it's time to move to services.